# Issues referencing a light in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

I'm trying to make a driving game in Unity, and as part of it, I'm trying to make a traffic light blink on and off.

This is my script, which I attached to the traffic light. The hierarchy of the traffic light is:

> TrafficLight_A (the base traffic light)
>
> - RedLight (the light I'm trying to make flash)

```
    using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 
 public class Blink_Light : MonoBehaviour
 {

     public float totalSeconds = 2;     // The total of seconds the flash wil last
     public float maxIntensity = 8;     // The maximum intensity the flash will reach
     public Light myLight = Light RedLight;        // The light (error)
 
     public IEnumerator flashNow ()
     {
         float waitTime = totalSeconds / 2;                        
         // Get half of the seconds (One half to get brighter and one to get darker)
         while (myLight.intensity < maxIntensity) {
             myLight.intensity += Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        // Increase intensity
             yield return null;
         }
         while (myLight.intensity > 0) {
             myLight.intensity -= Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        //Decrease intensity
            yield return null;
         }
         yield return null;
     }
 }
```

However, I get an error:

```
Assets/Blink_Script/Blink_Light.cs: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol "RedLight"
```

What can I do to fix this? (I'm somewhat new to `C#`)

Comment: Where is the Blink.cs code? Or is what you posted Blink.cs?  If so, you probably want to change it to Flash.cs or change the name of the class from Flash to Blink.  Either way, are you sure RedLight exists in the scene?  To make sure it is being set properly set it in the inspector instead.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 As shown by the error message, it's in `/Blink_Script/Blink.cs`. It's attached to `TrafficLight_A` as a script component. (The code above is `Blink.cs`, but when I change the class definition to `Blink`, I get `Assets/Blink_Script/Blink.cs(4,15): error CS0101: The namespace 'global::' already contains a definition for 'Blink'.

Comment: See edit, but I meant please post the Blink.cs code or if what you posted IS Blink.cs then the class should also be called Blink.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 I did post `Blink.cs`. I changed both the class name and the script name to `Blink_Light` and the error still occurs.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to fix the issue, just to direct you towards good programming practice.  The name of your .cs file should always be the same as your class name as a best practice.

Comment: By the way, using a `Light` for things we call "lights" isn't the best plan. `Light`s are for when *illumination* is needed: that is, shadows. For display, softly glowing, or similar, its better to use a mesh with a material that ignores scene lighting ("full bright" or "unlit") as it is far faster to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your hierarchy, you are trying to access a `Light` component from a GameObject named "RedLight" which is a child of the "TrafficLight_A" GameObject. To do that, use pass "TrafficLight_A/RedLight" to the `GameObject.Find` function which finds the RedLight GameObject then `GetComponent<Light>()` to retrieve the `Light` component. You can do that in the `Awake` or `Start` function.

Whenever you need to find a child object, the "/" is used just like you would in file path.

```
public float totalSeconds = 2;     // The total of seconds the flash wil last
public float maxIntensity = 8;     // The maximum intensity the flash will reach
public Light myLight;

void Awake()
{
    //Find the RedLight
    GameObject redlight = GameObject.Find("TrafficLight_A/RedLight");
    //Get the Light component attached to it
    myLight = redlight.GetComponent<Light>();
}

public IEnumerator flashNow()
{
    float waitTime = totalSeconds / 2;
    // Get half of the seconds (One half to get brighter and one to get darker)
    while (myLight.intensity < maxIntensity)
    {
        myLight.intensity += Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        // Increase intensity
        yield return null;
    }
    while (myLight.intensity > 0)
    {
        myLight.intensity -= Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        //Decrease intensity
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: It fixed the error, and can find the `RedLight`! But, for some reason, it won't flash. :(

Comment: Your reference issue is solved. You can create new question for your flashing issue. I am sure many people like deHugo can help you