# Light isn't flashing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

After solving a [ReferenceError with my `Flash_Light.cs` script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765578/issues-referencing-a-light-in-unity), I've been having an issue where the target light in the script won't flash.

The `Flash_Light` script is attached to `LampPost_A_Blink1`,`LampPost_A_Blink1` has a light attached (called `RedLight`), and the script seems to work perfectly (no warnings or errors). However, the light won't flash.

My script is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class Blink_Light : MonoBehaviour
 {

     public float totalSeconds = 2;     // The total of seconds the flash wil last
    public float maxIntensity = 8;     // The maximum intensity the flash will reach
    public Light myLight;

    void Awake()
    {
        //Find the RedLight
        GameObject redlight = GameObject.Find("LampPost_A_Blink1/RedLight");
        //Get the Light component attached to it
        myLight = redlight.GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    public IEnumerator flashNow()
    {
        float waitTime = totalSeconds / 2;
        // Get half of the seconds (One half to get brighter and one to get darker)

        while (myLight.intensity < maxIntensity)
        {
            myLight.intensity += Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        // Increase intensity
        }
        while (myLight.intensity > 0)
        {
            myLight.intensity -= Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        //Decrease intensity
        }
        yield return null;
    }
 }
```

When entering playmode, the light stays illuminated, instead of blinking like it should.

How can I fix this? (I have Unity 2017.2.0f3)

Comment: Dude, you just got your light connected.  Take some time and debug this yourself for a little while. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765578/issues-referencing-a-light-in-unity

Comment: Did you call the `flashNow` function? Call it at the end of the `Awake` funtion with `StartCoroutine(flashNow())` then see if the light changes.

Comment: @Programmer It does change - now, the light is off instead of on (but still not blinking D: ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's `Time.deltaTime` will be *the-same* in a function or a loop in a function. It changes every frame but calling a function once is one frame. The problem is that you used it in a `while` loop without waiting for the next frame so you get the-same value.

Also, because you are not waiting for a frame, instead of the code executing over multiple frames, it will execute in one frame only and you won't be able to see the changes on the light. The solution to this is to put  `yield return null` in each `while` loop. It will make the code in the `while` loop run every frame until the condition is met then it exit.

```
public IEnumerator flashNow()
{
    float waitTime = totalSeconds / 2;
    // Get half of the seconds (One half to get brighter and one to get darker)

    while (myLight.intensity < maxIntensity)
    {
        myLight.intensity += Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        // Increase intensity
        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
    while (myLight.intensity > 0)
    {
        myLight.intensity -= Time.deltaTime / waitTime;        //Decrease intensity
        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Since this is a caroutine function, don't forget to call or start it with `StartCoroutine(flashNow())`:

Comment: The light flashes! :D But it stops after the second while loop (when the intensity is 0).

Comment: Your current code is supposed to go up to 8 then back to 0. What do you expect?

Comment: I fixed the stopping issue by wrapping the `while` loops in `while(true) { (while loops go here) }`.

Comment: Looks like you want it to repeat forever. If that's true then there you go. Note that if what you want to do is flicker a right then this is not the correct way to do it.